# Compute multiplication of two polynomials.

Tags: polynomials

Suppose I have a polynomial in its coefficients representation

$$P(x) = [a_0, 0, a_2, 0, a_4, 0, a_6 ... a_p]$$

I want to calculate $$P(x - c) \times P(x + c)$$ where it is guaranteed that 
$[a_0, a_2 .. ] $ are integers and $c = \sqrt{n}$ where $n$ is also integer

I want the coefficient representation of $G(x)$ where
$$G(x) = P(x - c) \times P(x+c)$$

What is the efficient way to compute this, as it is guaranteed that $$ G(x) = [b_0, 0, b_2, 0, b_4, 0, b_6 .... b_g]$$ and $[b_0, b_2, b_4 ...]$ are integers

I have tried using Taylor expansion for shifting the polynomials and multiplying them. I was wondering if Taylor expansion can be skipped because right now my solution includes Taylor expansion + Multiplication.
Skipping the Taylor expansion will help me not deal with the precision of coefficients

Comment: what has been tried ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Right now my solution includes using Taylor expansion for calculating the shift and then multiplying them

Comment: hint:  123456789 and 234567891 can be multiplied ... how.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I assume these numbers being cyclic shifts of each other gives them a special property? I am sorry, I don't know it!
I hope it wasn't sarcastic for there isn't any anything you can do!

Comment: The coefficients of the product $R(x)=Q(x-a)Q(x+a)$ (which is an even function) are $\dfrac{R^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$, **maybe**, for the computation, let $Q(x)=:f(x^2)=f(g(x))$ with $g(x)=x^2$, and from there use the Faa di Bruno formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) but will it work ?

Comment: it was pointing out, that  decimal numbers are evaluations of a polynomial with x=10.

Comment: Somebody is wanting this question to be closed... I don't understand. This is a perfectly written question.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Yes, I still didn't get the hint ! If you could elaborate it bit more.

Comment: @JeanMarie I will do some paperwork and check. In case you get something definitive, do post is as an answer.

Comment: 123456789= $1x^8+2x^7+3x^6+4x^5+5x^4+6x^3+7x^2+8x^1+9x^0$   I guess I got lost in the notation.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I got that part. After you mentioned it being a polynomial with x = 10. What I didn't get is, how is this a hint?

Comment: I'm not sure anymore, because I'm not sure where c comes into play.  my main point is you can multiply polynomials like you do integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean by efficient, but I gather that staying with integers (in spite of the presence of $c=\sqrt{n}$) may be a priority?

In that case you may note that $P(x+c)=Q(x)+c R(x)$, $P(x-c)=Q(x)-cR(x)$ where $Q$ and $R$ are integer polynomials that you may calculate using e.g. recursion and a vector representation of powers $(x+c)^k$ (and only integers calculus), and then  that $P(x+c)P(x-c)= Q(x)^2 - c^2 R(x)^2$.

Example: $P(x)=2+5x^2+x^4$, $c=\sqrt{n}$.

$$(x+c)^2 = [c^2+x^2] + c [2x] = [n+x^2] + c [2x]$$
 is a splitting of the above mentioned form, the first of degree two, the second of degree one. Then using e.g. Cauchy multiplication you may calculate (degree 4 and 3, respectively):

$$(x+c)^4 = (x+c)^2(x+c)^2 =[n^2+ 6n x^2 + x^4] + c[4x^3+4n x]$$

Adding terms, $$P(x+c)=  [2 + 5(n+x^2) + (n^2+6nx^2+x^4)] + c[2x + (4x^3+4nx)]$$
In practice you may represent every polynomial of the form $Q(x)+cR(x)$ by two vectors (sufficiently large depending on the degree of $P$). Very similar to representing complex numbers or complex polynomials.

Comment: I didn't quite understand how do you calculate $Q(x)$ or $R(x)$? Could you please explain with an example probably?

Comment: Do you know about "Cauchy product"?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product

Comment: Yes, I have an idea about it.